# Pdo request, I really don't get it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, between

Juste an simple pdo request that doesn't work. I don't get it. Really don't.

```
$d = strtotime("today");
$start_week = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$d);
$start = date("Y-m-d",$start_week); 

$s1 = $db->prepare("SELECT leads where humeur != 'Doublon' and date_import between :start and :end");
$s1->bindParam(':start', $start);
$s1->bindParam(':end', $today);

try{
  $s1->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Exception reçue : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Got that.

> Exception reçue : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where humeur != 'Doublon' and date_import between '2015-03-29' and '2015-04-01'' at line 1

If someone sees something I don't, I'll be grateful.

Comment: You didn't include the `FROM table` - `SELECT leads FROM yourTable where humeur`

Comment: needs a table in the query

Comment: It must be defined otherwise the error would be different to what is included in the question.

Comment: In addition to the other recommendations, in the provided code `$today` is not defined.

Comment: Ok guys guys, sorry, I feel ashamed.... :)

Comment: You should at the very least accept one of the two answers since both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect, it is missing the table you want to select from.

You need to update your query like so:

```
$d = strtotime("today");
$start_week = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$d);
$start = date("Y-m-d",$start_week); 

// Replace tableName with the actual name of the table
$s1 = $db->prepare("SELECT leads FROM tableName where humeur != 'Doublon' and date_import between :start and :end");
$s1->bindParam(':start', $start);
$s1->bindParam(':end', $today);

try{
  $s1->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Exception reçue : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your connexion:

```
$hostname_conn = "xxxx";
$database_conn = "xxx";
$username_conn = "xxx";
$password_conn = "xxx";
```

PDO

```
try{ 
$bdd=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_conn; dbname=$database_conn","$username_conn","$password_conn");
$bdd->EXEC('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}catch(Exception $e){
    die('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Now your request:

```
$s1 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT leads from yourtable where humeur != 'Doublon' and date_import between :start and :end");
$s1->bindParam(':start', $start);
$s1->bindParam(':end', $today);
$s1->execute();

while ($row = $s1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  ...;
}
```